# Web Service Call for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, rest, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am completely new to windows phone app development. I just installed the Visual Studio 2015 and started working on a new app. Was going all smooth until the time arrived to call a web service of my back-office. First I was unable to debug why and where the code threw exception. Then I realized and tried writing the exception's message to a text block.
Note I have tried using the same code what I got from working examples found by Googling.

```
   Error: "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"
```

Code:

```
public async Task<dynamic> getHomeCategories()
{
    string url = string.Format("my working api url");
    var uri = new Uri(url);
    var client = new HttpClient();
    dynamic resultObj = "";

    //using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
        resultObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(response);
        wsresult.Text = "okay";
        return resultObj;
    }
    catch(Exception Ex) { 
        wsresult.Text = Ex.Message.ToString(); return resultObj;   
    }            
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what response you are getting??Please Put your response here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   HttpResponseMessage response;
    public async Task<string> webserviceResponse(string HttpMethod)
    {      
        // check internet connection is available or not   

        if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() == true)
        {
           // CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2000); // 2 seconds
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            MultipartFormDataContent mfdc = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            mfdc.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
            string GenrateUrl = "your url";

            if (HttpMethod == "POST")
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync(GenrateUrl, mfdc);

            }
            else if (HttpMethod == "PUT")
            {
                response = await client.PutAsync(GenrateUrl, mfdc);
            }
            else if (HttpMethod == "GET")
            {
                response = await client.GetAsync(GenrateUrl);
            }
            var respon = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string convert_response = respon.ToString();
            return convert_response;
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your use of dynamic types giving you the expection

```
dynamic resultObj = "";
```

This makes resultObj a string

```
resultObj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(response);
```

The you try and stick a class in it.  I would recommend you parse the response in to a type.